# ERROR 59001 - “unknown web session id” (PagSeguro getPaymentMethods)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm implementing PagSeguro's Transparent Checkout, but I always get an error when trying to search for payment methods. I tried to search the internet and even exchange ideas with my cooworker, but we were unable to solve this problem.

> The reference:
>   https://dev.pagseguro.uol.com.br/reference#transparente-biblioteca-javascript

**CODE:**

```
 <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
            },
            methods: {
                gerarSessao() {
                    var parser, xmlDoc, parserId;
                    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                            //PEGAMOS A REPOSTA EM TEXTO
                            var id = this.responseText;
                            parser = new DOMParser();
                            //PARSER XML
                            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(id, "text/xml")
                            parserId = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue

                            //SETAMOS O ID DA SESSÃO NO PAG SEGURO (BIBLIOTECA)
                            PagSeguroDirectPayment.setSessionId(parserId);

                        } else if (this.readyState == 401) {
                            console.log(this.readyState)
                        }
                    };
                    xhttp.open("POST", "https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/sessions?email=MEU-EMAIL-PASSADO-DIRETO&token=MEU-TOKEN-PASSADO-DIRETO", true);
                    xhttp.send();
                },

                getPaymentMethods() {
                    PagSeguroDirectPayment.getPaymentMethods({
                        amount: 500.00,
                        success: function (response) {
                            // Retorna os meios de pagamento disponíveis.
                            console.log(response)
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            // Callback para chamadas que falharam.
                            console.log(response)
                        },
                        complete: function (response) {
                            // Callback para todas chamadas.
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            mounted() {
                this.gerarSessao()
                this.getPaymentMethods()
            }
        })
```

Comment: 'PagSeguroDirectPayment.setSessionId(parserId);' that's the line you're getting the error? What's the value of 'parserId' variable?

Comment: @MarceloTheWizzardCoder Yes! The value is: 7b856962f5414ada8e4ff60bb5494f06

Comment: The endpoint used in the DOCS are 'https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/?email=email&token=token' and you're using 'https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/sessions'. Is this the correct endpoint?

Comment: @MarceloTheWizzardCoder If I use this endpoint, return this error: index.html:48 POST https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/?email=email&token=token 405 (Method Not Allowed). That's why I use the "Environments available for integration" (../v2/sessions) (on DOC)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, looks like PagSeguro's are failing the session validation. Maybe you can get some help with their support team

Comment: @MarceloTheWizzardCoder I gonna try this, thanks for help!